# Picking out Just JSON Data Returned from ASP.NET MVC3 controller Update

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got data returned from my JavaScript client that just includes the data that has changed.  That is, I may have an array with each row containing 10 columns of JSON downloaded, but on the Update, only the data that is returned to me is the data that got updated.  On my update, I only want to update those columns that are changed (not all of them).

In other words, I have code like below but because I'm passing in an instance of the "President" class, I have no way of knowing what actually came in on the original JSON.

How can I just update what comes into my MVC3 update method and not all columns.  That is, 8 of the columns may not come in and will be null in the "data" parameter passed in. I don't want to wipe out all my data because of that.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Update(President data)
    {
        bool success = false;
        string message = "no record found";
        if (data != null && data.Id > 0)
        {
            using (var db = new USPresidentsDb())
            {
                var rec = db.Presidents.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == data.Id);
                rec.FirstName = data.FirstName;
                db.SaveChanges();
                success = true;
                message = "Update method called successfully";
            }
        }

        return Json(new
        {
            data,
            success,
            message
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rec.FirstName = data.FirstName ?? rec.FirstName;
```

Comment: Hi Maess, this is exactly what I don't want to do. It will erase my real data in FirstName.  FirstName was not returned in the JSON and the value in the "data.FirstName" will be null.  That is, FirstName did not change so it was not pushed up as JSON.Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.(click on this box to dismiss)...HOLD ON, LET ME THINK ABOUT THIS.

Comment: you are selecting the rec from the data source (at least I assume db is your context) therefore, it should be loaded with the current value of 'FirstName', the above statement will set 'FirstName' to its current value if data.FirstName is null.

Comment: Hi Maess, Two problems.  First, I'm hoping for a more general way to handle this so I don't have to explicity write code in every controller for every column.  Second, the above method only works for nullable columns.  I have non-nullable boolean columns for example that this method would not work for.  I'm not sure what would come back, but I'm guessing the default value of boolean will be returned.

Comment: Ok, I read your question as stating that the "columns will not come in and will be null" meaning you meant that the columns will be null.

Answer (score 0):

I would use reflection in this case because the code will be too messy like

```
if (data.FirstName != null)
   rec.FirstName = data.FirstName
.
.
.
```

and so on for all the fields

Using reflection, it would be easier to do this. See this method

```
public static void CopyOnlyModifiedData<T>(T source, ref T destination)
{
    foreach (var propertyInfo in source.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(source, null);
        if (value!= null && !value.GetType().IsValueType)
        {
            destination.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name, value.GetType()).SetValue(destination, value, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
CopyOnlyModifiedData<President>(data, ref rec);
```

*Please mind that, this won't work for `value` type properties.*